# BlueJ Error: "Incompatible types: int cannot be converted java.lang.String" AND "Incompatible types: java.lang.String cannot be converted to int"

Tags: java, bluej

I'm very new to coding and after trying multiple solutions I came up with, I still can't figure out why what I'm doing is wrong. This is my full code:

```
public class Student {
  private String name;
  private String grade;
  private String gender;
  private int number;

  public Student( String name,  String grade, String gender, int number ) {
    this.name = name;
    this.grade = grade;
    this.gender = gender;
    this.number = number;
  }

  public String getName() {
    return name;
  }

  public void setName( String name ) {
    this.name = name;
  }

  public String getGrade() {
   return grade;
  }

  public void setGrade( String grade ) {
    this.grade = grade;
  }

  public String getGender() {
    return gender;
  }

  public void setGender( String gender ) {
    this.gender = gender;
  }

  public String getNumber() {
    return number;
  }

  public void setNumber( String number ) {
    this.number = number;
  }
}
```

As you can probably see, I'm trying to not only be able to add a new name/grade/gender/int number when I first use an object, but also by using methods.

The problem I'm getting seems to be caused in this part:

```
public String getNumber() {
  return number;
}

public void setNumber( String number ) {
  this.number = number;
}
```

When I hover over "number" in the second line, BlueJ gives the following error: **"Incompatible types: int cannot be converted to java.lang.String"**.

Though when I hover over "number" in the fifth line, BlueJ gives the error: **"Incompatible types: java.lang.String cannot be converted to int"**.

I've tried searching on this website for similar problems, but haven't found any where they tried to use an int number to be filled in by the use of methods.

Comment: `number` is a `int` not a `String`, change your methods signatures to `public int getNumber()` and `public void setNumber( int number )` .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

String and int are **two** different types, and in contrast to Integer and int, there is no compiler-magic to turn the one into the other automatically.

But there are various helper methods to work around this, like:

```
String asString = Integer.toString(123);
```

which turns `int` into `String`; and

```
int number = Integer.parseInt("123");
```

for the other way round.

And just for the record: the fact that you can write

```
Integer integerObject = 5;
```

is called [auto-boxing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html).